# Replace space and forward slash with hyphen in URL php

Tags: php

I am trying to replace a space and forward slash in a url with a hyphen e.g www.example.com/car/**bmw/porsche** where bmw/porsche is one value..but it doesn't seem to be working for the forward slash.

This is what I have for the space which works:

```
$name = str_replace("-", " ", $request[2]);
$id = $category->find_id_by_name($name);
```

But when I add it for the forward slash, it doesn't work.. although it still works for the space:

```
$name = str_replace(array("-","//"), " ", $request[2]);
$id = $category->find_id_by_name($name);
```

How would I change this to work?

**EDIT**

So I changed the code to the following:

```
$char = " ";
$name = str_replace("-", $char, $request[2]);
$id = $category->find_id_by_name($name);
```

Then I put the `$char` in an array like this `$char = array(" ", "/");` Which gave me the following: `Notice: Array to string conversion` Then I tried getting them by their indexes like this:

```
$name = str_replace("-", $char[0], $request[2]);<-- works for forward slash but not space

$name = str_replace("-", $char[1], $request[2]);<-- works for space but not forward slash
```

I just can't seem to get them to work together :(

---

**[NEW EDIT]**

```
class CarController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {

        $category = new Application_Model_CarMapper();
        $gcat = $this->getRequest()->getPathInfo();

        $request = explode("/", $gcat);
        //die(print_r($request));

        if (isset($request[2])) {
            $char = array("/"," ");
            $name = str_replace("-", $char, $request[2]);//<-- "-" and "$char swapped over"
            $id = $category->find_id_by_name($name);
            $this->view->title = $id['name'];
            //die(print_r($request));

            $this->view->selectsub = $category->get_sub_cat_select($id['id']);


        }
    }

}
```

**VAR DUMP**

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string 'car' (length=3)
  2 => string 'bmw-porsche' (length=11)
  3 => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: where are you defining the $request[2] variable? can you post the result of `var_dump($request);` please?

Comment: Please see my edit above... I have shown the complete code

Comment: What values does $name have? I think that in the example you want it to be bmw-porsche at the end. What are you actually getting?

Comment: with the code above it just throws back an error saying `Notice: Array to string conversion` Are you talking about values like `bmw/porsche`?

Comment: when i use an index for char instead as shown in my first edit that works but not for both

Comment: I was talking about the example you gave. Looking at the URL and the description I think that you expect $request[2] to be bmw/porsche at the beginning and want your code to convert it to bmw-porsche. Is that correct? What is the code actually outputting? In order to reply to a user you should put @username at the beginning of the comment. That way I get a notification.

Comment: @Belinda yes that is correct. It displays the page but doesn't display the title as how i pushed it to the view and just displays the error message at the bottom in orange: `Notice: Array to string conversion`, i have my echo in a seperate file as follows.. `<p><?php echo ucwords(strtoupper($this->title));?> PRODUCTS &#45;</p>` However, using the index `$name = str_replace($char[0], "-", $request[2]);` does return back the actual name when i type bmw-porsche at the end of the browser. `request[2]` retrieves all the categories from the database where the index is the field name

Comment: @Belinda hope i am making some sort of sense?

Comment: Try a var_dump of $request, to make sure that you are getting what you think you are.

Comment: @Belinda Oops, i forgot to mention that my search and replace works backwards, i have edited my code above so you can see what i mean and i have displayed my var dump too..

Comment: Unless I've really got something wrong $request[2] seems to already be what you want in that example.

Comment: @Belinda that's what it shows in the var dump however it doesn't display it at all when i echo it out, it just displays that string error... how would i bypass that??

Comment: If you change `str_replace("-", $char, $request[2]);` to `str_replace($char, "-", $request[2]);` what happens?

Comment: @Belinda it displays no error but it also doesn't display anything at all either

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Add an echo or var_dump for $name after the replace.

Comment: @Belinda don't worry about it, i have it working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for this:

```
$myUri = "Bmw/Porsche"; // Or set it accordingly by retreiving from your database
$uriCompatible = urlencode($myUri); // Results in "Bmw%2FPorsche"
$myUrl = "www.example.com/car/" . $uriCompatible;
```

You could use [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to retreive it:

```
echo $request[2]; // Results in "Bmw%2FPorsche"
$myUri = urldecode($request[2]); // Results in "Bmw/Porsche";
```

Comment: How could this example work with the code i provided above? there are many values for this so with the code you have shown, it would be long winded and i would like it to work with what i have above

Comment: You can run all variables you have through `urlencode()` before concatenating them to any URL. In your case `urlencode($request[2])`.

Comment: Edit, one thing is unclear to me, are you trying to build a valid URL in which your value is one value or are you trying to retreive this value from a provided URL? In the latter case, how would you know which slashes are part of the value and which aren't?

Comment: In a way, both. I want to enter in the URL say example.com/cars/bmw-porsche where bmw-porsche is the value in the table but it is stored in the table as bmw/porsche so that is unvalid to enter in the url.. once i have entered in this URL it should display all this data for bmw/porsche, which i test by pushing a title to the view and echoing it out.. eg. I want so that if i enter `example.com/cars/bmw-porsche` it echoes out that specific category onto the page.. `Welcome to the Bmw/Porsche products`

Comment: Ok building the link with `urlencode()` would result in `Bmw%xxPorsche` where `%xx` is the actual value for a slash. Upon getting this value you should get `Bmw/Porsche` back using `urldecode()` afterwards.

Comment: @ash: Note I've clarified my answer a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

`I am trying to replace a space and forward slash in a url with a hyphen`

then you should have

```
$name = str_replace(" ", "-", $request[2]);
```

and

```
$name = str_replace(array(" ","/"), "-", $request[2]);
```

Comment: This does not work either, i think my str_replace is working kinda backwards so i am quessing i would have to put the forward slash in an array with the space but i am not sure how to go about this

Comment: Since you note that it might be working backwards, could you execute this and tell me what it outputs? str_replace("A", "B", "AB");

Comment: @nvanesch.. `BB` it replace `A` with `B`

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead of double and it will work. Like this:

```
$name = str_replace(array('-','/'), " ", $request[2]);
$id = $category->find_id_by_name($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to escape the "/". backslashed need to be escaped here, but not foreward slashes.

```
$name = str_replace(array("-","/"), " ", $request[2]);
$id = $category->find_id_by_name($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape forward slashes. try this

```
$name = str_replace(array("-",'/'), " ", $request[2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$name = str_replace(array("-","/"), " ", $request[2]);
```